# My column is not left justified when it wraps in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row of information which I need to break into two rows for a small screen.  I thought I could do it by reserving 6 columns for each of the first two parts of the row so the next two parts would automatically wrap to the next line.  Here is the code I tried.

```
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6  text-left "><label>Rule Number: </label></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 text-left">555555</div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 text-left "><label>Rule Title:</label></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left">This is my title </div>
        </div>
```

I want the output to look like this.

Rule Number:               555555

Rule Title:                This is my title.

But it looks like this.

Rule Number:               555555

```
             Rule Title:
```

This is my title.

If my Rule number is big enough to wrap around then I get the output I want.  Is there a way to accomplish what I want in bootstrap?  (Sorry the Rule Title: looks like code, I didn't know how to add spaces and not have it treat it like code).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  Using the `clearfix` class along with the `visible-xs` class fixed the problem.

```
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 text-left">&nbsp</div><div class = "clearfix visible-xs"></div>
```